# how to insert data from lineEdit to tableWidget in PyQt4?

Tags: python, uitableview, pyqt4

I am new in PyQt,currently working on a form where user will insert data into lineEdit and after submitting the data will be shown in the tablewidget.
I am reading data fro lineEdit and printing it but unfortunately not finding any way to add lineEdit  data to the tableWidget.The data should appear in the exact cell.
It will be very helpful if the way is described.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you adding a row with insertRow() first? Here's a quick example app that works for me. Set the row and column when calling setItem().

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QLineEdit, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, \
    QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # When 'enter' is pressed call the 'addItem' function.
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.addItem)

    def addItem(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()

        # Get the number of rows in the TableWidget and insert
        # a new row at the end.
        lastrow = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(lastrow)

        item = QTableWidgetItem(text)

        # .setItem(row, column, item)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(lastrow, 0, item)
```